# Thumbnail image not visible in post shortcode in WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't understand why the thumbnail isn't in the code. It's the `get_the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail')` that isn't working. I'm confused an have spent to many hours to try to solve this by my self, but I don't see the error. Do you?

```html
function show_posts() {

$html = "";
$extra_css = "";

$latestPosts = new WP_Query('cat=5&posts_per_page=1');

if($latestPosts->have_posts()): while($latestPosts->have_posts()): 

$latestPosts->the_post();

if (has_post_thumbnail) $extra_css = "has-thumbnail";

$html = "<article class='post {$extra_css}'>";

$html .= "<div class='post-thumbnail'>";

$html .= "<a href='" . get_the_permalink() . "'>" . get_the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') . "</a>";
 
$html .= "<div class='post-thumbnail-date'></h4>" . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . "<h4></div>";

$html .= "</div><!-- end post-thumbnail -->";

$html .= "<h3><a href='" . get_the_permalink() . "'>" . get_the_title() . "</a></h3>";

$html .= "<p class='post-info'>" . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . " | Av " . get_the_author() . "</p>";

$html .= "<p class='post-text'>" . get_the_excerpt() . "<a href='" . get_the_permalink() . "'> Läs mer...</a>"; 

$html .= "</p>";

$html .= "</article>";

endwhile;

else:

// Error message

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

return $html;

}
```

Comment: convert  `if (has_post_thumbnail)` to `if ( has_post_thumbnail() )` and place the code related to the condition inside block, also check [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to learn how to turn on error reporting.

Comment: @Danijel Thanks, I had missed that, but it didn't help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of [get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) function is optional post ID and second parameter is thumbnail size...

Try use this: get_the_post_thumbnail(null, 'thumbnail') or instead of null custom/global $post->ID...

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It worked with 'null', but it's strange that I have to use this, because I also has the same code in the front-page.php and that works with the image of the thumbnail and without the 'null'. I got this problem when I was creating some shortcode to be able to show the last post anywhere one the pages and then it didn't work. And it didn't work 'get_post_thumbnail_id();' It also seems that there is a difference between the use of 'get' or not when calling WP functions!? Why 'null' in the call to the function?

Comment: When you use the null value for the first parameter, within the function is called get_the_ID(), which is essentially the same as global $post->ID...